# как закрыть всплывающее окно firefox с помощью selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Появляеться такое окно при открытии skype в  firefox [image: alert]

как нажать кнопку "отмена" с помощью selenium python.
буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Судя по [всему](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652763/selenium-c-sharp-how-to-handle-alert-open-pick-an-app) - никак. Там что то типа "это окно на уровне системы и селениум его не видит" (странно почему) и нажимать нужно сторонними средствами. Также для хрома вроде есть флаг `--disable-default-apps`, а для ff непонятно что такого есть.

Answer (score 0):

найти элемент по тексту и отправить нажатие

```
ln=driver.find_element_by_link_text("Отмена")
ln.click()
```

Comment: не работает.
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  ln = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Отмена")
Message: Unable to locate element: Отмена
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16

Comment: это alert firefox

Comment: @Mirai тогда возможно эмуляция таба и энтереа? Таб чтобы переключится между кнопками.

Comment: это уже пробовал

Comment: @Mirai то есть не обрабатываются табы?

Comment: нет, это не работает, я уже все перепробывал

Comment: он просто не взаимодействует с этим аlert

Comment: @Mirai  нагуглилось `driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();`

Comment: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo'

Comment: @Mirai https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-alert-popup-selenium-python/ вроде расписано же

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]